# Bootstrap images in carousel not sliding

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using twitters bootstrap carousel, sometimes images slide , sometimes they dont..
 and when they do not

```
TypeError: $next[0] is undefined


    $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow    

    $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow     bootstrap.js (line 351)
```

this error comes. I have no know what does that mean.

I am setting html content of carousel div from Javascript, act, i am showing 3 images in carousel instead of one/like thumbnails:
vaersion:/* ===================================================
 * bootstrap-transition.js v2.0.4

code in javascript:

```
drawCarousel = function(result){
    var HasImages=false;
    var data_url=result['ImagesResult'];
    var data_details=result['ImageDetail'];
    var URLList = data_url["ImageUrls"];
    var ImageDetails=data_details["ImageDetails"];
    if(data_url==""){
        html+="NO Images To Display";       
    }
    html = "";
    var isFirst = true;
    num=0;
    for(var i=0;i<URLList.length;i++){ 
        HasImages=true;
        if(isFirst == true){   
                if(num==0){
                    html+="<div class='item active'><ul class=\"thumbnails\"><li class=\"span2\"><div class=\"thumbnail\" style=\"vertical-align:middle !important;\"><img src='" +URLList[i]["url"]+"' alt='' /></div></li>";          
                    num=num+1;
                }
                else{
                    html+="<li class=\"span2\"><div class=\"thumbnail\"><img src='" +URLList[i]["url"]+"' alt='' /></div></li>";            
                    num=num+1;
                    if(num==3){
                        isFirst=false;
                        num=0;
                    }
                }
        }
        else {
            if(num==0){
                html+="</ul></div>";
                html+="<div class='item'><ul class=\"thumbnails\"><li class=\"span2\"><div class=\"thumbnail\"><img src='" +URLList[i]["url"]+"' alt='' /></div></li>";         
                num=num+1;
            } else{
                html+="<li class=\"span2\"><div class=\"thumbnail\"><img src='" +URLList[i]["url"]+"' alt='' /></div></li>";            
                num=num+1;
                if(num==3){
                    num=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    html+="<ul><div>";
    if(!HasImages){
        var no_image_message="<b>No Images to Display</b>";
        $(".carousel-inner").html(no_image_message);    

    }else{
    $(".carousel-inner").html(html);
    }
};
```

Comment: can you show us your HTML markup and any js code you may be using? also what Bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: can you post you html code here??

Comment: i have edited..Please see to it once